# Web component doesn't listen to event emitted by other component

Tags: javascript, web-component

`console.log` doesn't get executed because `componentB` does not receive the event it is listening to from `componentA`.

```
class componentA extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('custom-event', {
            bubbles: true,
            composed: true
        }));
    }
}
  
window.customElements.define('component-a', componentA);
  
class componentB extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        document.addEventListener('custom-event', (event) => {
            console.log('ok');
        });
    }
}

window.customElements.define('component-b', componentB);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="logic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <component-a></component-a>
  <component-b></component-b>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to replace this.dispatchEvent with document.dispatchEvent but it did'nt change the output. Note that I don't get any error messages.

Comment: Do you append a `component-b` to the DOM before `component-a`? Do you append either at all? Please create a minimal reproducible example of your problem.